# Remove Address bar from popup window using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Is it applicable to remove the address bar from a popup window using javascript
ex:

```
 window.open(url, 'liveMatches', 'width=720,height=800,toolbar=0,location=0, directories=0, status=0, menubar=0');
```

please advice,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Theoretically, yes. However, as with everything in Javascript, there's no guarantee that any given browser will support it or that the implementation will be consistent across browsers.

[This link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.open) as well as [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536651%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) indicate that the `location` option should control whether or not the Location/Address bar is shown. It should also have relatively good cross-browser support.

Comment: From that first link: Mozilla and Firefox users can force new windows to always render the location bar by setting dom.disable_window_open_feature.location to true in about:config or in their user.js file.
Firefox 3 note
In Firefox 3, dom.disable_window_open_feature.location now defaults to true,

Answer (score 18):

use jquery ui (http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/)

or perhaps

```
window.open(url,'liveMatches','directories=no,titlebar=no,toolbar=no,location=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=no,resizable=no,width=720,height=800');
```

**actually**

You cannot remove the address bar in modern browsers. That is a security measure. The user must always know what page they are on. Address bar also let user know, what type of security is on that page (HTTP or HTTPS).